# Window.open() without url path where I called the function

Tags: javascript, window.open

I've one problem with `window.open()` function.

I need to open each domain from this [list](https://www.brandnames.net/shop) and check if it's pointed to a lander.

I tried to get all domains with `document.querySelectorAll`... well, it doesn't matter.

When I calling function `window.open(domain, '_blank')` - it's always point to this url: brandnames.net/domain 
But I need only url to be as: google.com , not brandnames.net/google.com ( for example ).

As I understand `window.open()` - gives absolute path before (domain argument) - how I can to avoid this?

Comment: Or, maybe there is another function to do this?

Comment: may be domain root path settled to https://www.brandnames.net/shop by using proxy server or .htaccess file (redirect rules) that's why if you want to access  https://www.brandnames.net/ but it is redirecting to https://www.brandnames.net/shop automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try call `window.open` with a full protocol domain.

```
window.open('google.com', '_blank') // => Go to brandnames.net/google.com

window.open('https://google.com', '_blank') // => Go to https://google.com
```